# SASS nesting for attribute selector

Tags: sass, nested

I'm trying to nest a CSS selector to find several id's und classes that's being generated from drupal.

```
.wrapper, #wrapper {
    [class^="starts-with-"] { ... }
}
```

but it just won't work like i expect it to. The output is

```
 .wrapper[class^="starts-with-"],
 #wrapper[class^="starts-with-"] { ... }
```

i'd expect to select element IN .wrapper and #wrapper

```
.wrapper [class^="starts-with-"],
#wrapper [class^="starts-with-"] { ... }
```

Comment: What version of the SASS compiler are you using?  Your example seems to be giving me your desired behavior in 3.2.19+

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://sassmeister.com/gist/87ba61addeead52300f6

Comment: @denns, what happens if you explicitly set the parent selector like so: `& [class^="starts-with-"] { ... }`?